# Historical Grouping with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, chart.js

I am developing a project with node js and I want to use a chart in the project.

I am using MongoDB and I want to group information from database historically.

For example, let's say there is a template like this;

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61e3b88d3f14fb87161651c7"),
    "x": 78,
    "y": 157,
    "createdAt": "2022-09-21T10:11:40.479+00:00",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61e3b88d3f14fb87161651c8"),
    "x": 79,
    "y": 158,
    "createdAt": "2022-09-21T15:11:45.479+00:00",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61e3b88d3f14fb87161651c8"),
    "x": 80,
    "y": 159,
    "createdAt": "2022-09-23T15:11:45.479+00:00",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61e3b88d3f14fb87161651c8"),
    "x": 81,
    "y": 160,
    "createdAt": "2022-08-21T15:11:45.479+00:00",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61e3b88d3f14fb87161651c8"),
    "x": 82,
    "y": 161,
    "createdAt": "2021-07-22T15:11:45.479+00:00",
  },
]
```

Here are different data for days, months and years.
If my aim
01.2022. - > January data (all data from 1 January to 30 31 January)
2022 - > 2022 data (all data from January to December)
...

In short, I want to group the data as weekly, monthly, yearly.

How can I achieve this? The library I want to use is "chartjs".
 If there is another javascript library you recommend, I can use them as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, you'll want to look into using an aggregation pipeline that includes [the `$group` stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). More specifically, you will probably want to use [the `$dateTrunc` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) (along with [the `$dateFromString` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)). You can see an example of this basic approach with your sample data (with a few modified `_id` values) in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bloILmC7L4C).

But the limited information in the questions leaves a lot of things unclear. Some additional items for consideration:

- Apart from timespans, how else are you going to be filtering or grouping your data?
- What fields will you be processing when grouping the data together? In the sample playground I simply counted the number of items in each group as it wasn't clear what the `x` and `y` fields were meant to represent.
- The only reason that `$dateFromString` is needed currently is due to how the `createdAt` values are represented in your data. Ideally you should store them as dates not strings, which would remove the need for that extra operator as one benefit.

As a final note, you mention that this is being done to support some charting capabilities. If you are using an Atlas cluster to store this data then you might look into their Charts offering which may help reduce the amount of manual work that you need to do here.

Comment: Yes, I need a functional library that you mentioned in the last note, because the models change every time, do you know of a free library that I will need to create graphics for different models?

Comment: I think there are two separate concerns here.  The first is how to extract (or processing) the data from the database in a format that is meaningful for charting. The second is about libraries for charting directly.  As far as I know, things like `chartjs` and `amCharts` are certainly acceptable and widely used for the charting capabilities. The extraction/transformation of the data is a separate concern that is independent of the charting library. I mention MongoDB Charts specifically since it has built-in support for MongoDB directly which may help speed up development. Up to you though

Comment: I'm thinking of processing and sending the data in json format in the background.

Comment: Sure - that sounds fine. But I think that decision and discussion is unrelated to the question asked here which is about how to group documents in MongoDB by various lengths of time. Hopefully the answer above helped with the original question

Comment: Even though I didn't get a full answer, it made some things settle in my head, thanks man.
I can only provide this process with queries on the mongodb side, I need to filter the results of the queries and send them in json format, in short, I will have to write an api within the project.